# android: resume activity 2 from home menu

Tags: android, android-activity, resume

My application launches  `Activity1`. `Activity1` starts `Activity2`.
While on `Activity2`, if I press `Home` button and click on application's launch button, it starts again on `Activity1`.

Is it possible to resume `Activity2`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just Finish Activity1 on start up of Activity2 and don't finish activity2.

Write following Line

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

on Click event of home button or onpause() event.

Comment: That's the only option? I started activity2 as singleTask but it still launches activity1

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Normaly it should not happen that the application is restarted, unless the Android system needs more memory. Make sure to save your application state when Android notifies your application that it will be killed now.

Answer (score 0):

It is really old question, but i faces the exactly the same issue. I finally found the solution in manifest file.

I solved it by removing this property android:launchMode="singleInstance" of the Activity2 from manifest file and it works as expected.

Thanks,
Anil